# How to make apython program end when the only the enter key is pressed

Tags: python, python-3.x

The program is meant to end when the user types a blank line to achieve that i used '\n' return character and it works but on trying to redirect input from a text file i discover that once the program encounter a blank line it fails ie it ends on that line and ignores the rest.

for example if i have 
hello 
how are you

hello from the other side.
i must have called a thousand

the program ignores the hello from the other side.
i have tried changing the `'\n'` to `''` but the program no longer ends when i strike the enter key. Unfortunately i cannot change how the code is written since my only task is the end on blank line feature.

is there a way i can fix this.

```
import sys

def main():
     linenum = 1

     for line in sys.stdin:
          if line == '\n':
               sys.exit()
          print ("%3d. %s" % (linenum,line))
          linenum += 1

main()
```

Comment: "i discover that once the program encounter a blank line it fails ie it ends on that line and ignores the rest". Based on your description and title, it sounds like that's what you want. Your code `sys.exit`s when it detects a blank line (when you had `line == ''`). What do you need it to do? I'm confused.

Answer (score 0):

This exits the loop on newline

```
import sys

def main():
    linenum = 1

    for line in iter(sys.stdin.readline, '\n'):
        print ("%3d. %s" % (linenum,line))
        linenum += 1

main()
```